# Apply function to xmlNodeList in R (not whole xml file)

Tags: xml, r, xpath, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse information out from XML files using R. Each file can contain model records, and I want to end up with a list of objects representing those records.

Using [this file](http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?&db=pubmed&id=20203609,11959827,19409887&rettype=xml) as an example, I'm amingint to apply a function to represent the nodes under each `PubmedArticle`. When I try to do this using `xpathApply` from the `XML` library each record contains information from *every* pubmed article in the file (rather that apply the function to only those nodes under a given `PubmedArticle`). A minimal example to illustrate:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

raw_record <- getURI("http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?&db=pubmed&id=20203609,11959827,19409887&rettype=xml")
parsed <- xmlTreeParse(raw_record, useInternalNodes=TRUE)

get_title <- function(node) xpathApply(node, "//ArticleTitle", xmlValue)
xpathApply(parsed, "/PubmedArticleSet/PubmedArticle", get_title)
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] "Changes in Hox genes' structure and function during the evolution of the squamate body plan."
#
#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] "Cdx1 and Cdx2 have overlapping functions in anteroposterior patterning and     
# posterior axis elongation."
#
#[[1]][[3]]
#[1] "Axial patterning in snakes and caecilians: evidence for an alternative         interpretation of the Hox code."
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] "Changes in Hox genes' structure and function during the evolution of the squamate     body plan."
#
#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] "Cdx1 and Cdx2 have overlapping functions in anteroposterior patterning and posterior axis elongation."
#[SNIP]
```

What is the correct way to extract information *only* from each of the nodes created by `xpathApply` or `getNodeSet`?

Comment: @mrFlick - sorry, that's from `RCurl`. added this to the example now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to use a relative path in the `get_title` function Try

```
get_title <- function(node) xpathApply(node, ".//ArticleTitle", xmlValue)
titles<-xpathApply(parsed, "/PubmedArticleSet/PubmedArticle", get_title)
unlist(titles)
```

The `.//` means it will start looking anywhere below the current node. This will give you

```
[1] "Changes in Hox genes' structure and function during the evolution of the squamate body plan."          
[2] "Cdx1 and Cdx2 have overlapping functions in anteroposterior patterning and posterior axis elongation." 
[3] "Axial patterning in snakes and caecilians: evidence for an alternative interpretation of the Hox code."
```